# Compare object and array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there better and simpler way to compare object and array based on some key than using `for loop`

Example:

```js
var Obj = {
  ID: "27374b25-a97b-4676-889b-32d87087c72d",
  Name: "Kenny J. Jones",
  City: "Dallas, TX"
};
var Array = [{
    ID: "27374b25-a97b-4676-889b-32d87087c72d",
    Name: "Kenny J. Jones",
    City: "Dallas, TX"
  },
  {
    ID: "50d861e8-793f-4d6c-87f4-09cf7312310f",
    Name: "Denise L. Demeo",
    City: "Pine, LA 70438"
  },
  {
    ID: "95a03cda-5f26-4b60-b070-e92885f1a9b7",
    Name: "Jose A. Steed",
    City: "Florence, SC 29501"
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
  if (Obj.ID === Array[i].ID) {
    Array[i].Person = true;
  }
}
console.log(Array);
```

What if I have for example `10.000` objects in this array. Is it that bad for performance?

Comment: "Better" and "Simpler" are pretty subjective.

Comment: I update question I'm asking because of performance if you have bigger data in an array.

Comment: What you are doing is fine in terms of readability and performance.

Answer (score 0):

More compact and same perfomance:

```js
var Obj = {
  ID: "27374b25-a97b-4676-889b-32d87087c72d",
  Name: "Kenny J. Jones",
  City: "Dallas, TX"
};
var myArray = [{
    ID: "27374b25-a97b-4676-889b-32d87087c72d",
    Name: "Kenny J. Jones",
    City: "Dallas, TX"
  },
  {
    ID: "50d861e8-793f-4d6c-87f4-09cf7312310f",
    Name: "Denise L. Demeo",
    City: "Pine, LA 70438"
  },
  {
    ID: "95a03cda-5f26-4b60-b070-e92885f1a9b7",
    Name: "Jose A. Steed",
    City: "Florence, SC 29501"
  }
];

myArray.filter(x => x.ID === Obj.ID).forEach(x => {
  x.Person = true;
});

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

For More optimization, 
please Use **Break** once you get the match

```
var end = Array.length;
var i = 0 
for (i; i < end i++) {
  if (Obj.ID === Array[i].ID) {
    Array[i].Person = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your return should be a break; ;)

Comment: @DanielZiegler : thanx, I missed that due to hurry

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
  Id: "27374b25-a97b-4676-889b-32d87087c72d",
  Name: "Kenny J. Jones",
  City: "Dallas, TX"
};

const arr = [
  {
    Id: "27374b25-a97b-4676-889b-32d87087c72d",
    Name: "Kenny J. Jones",
    City: "Dallas, TX"
  },
  {
    Id: "50d861e8-793f-4d6c-87f4-09cf7312310f",
    Name: "Denise L. Demeo",
    City: "Pine, LA 70438"
  },
  {
    Id: "95a03cda-5f26-4b60-b070-e92885f1a9b7",
    Name: "Jose A. Steed",
    City: "Florence, SC 29501"
  }
];
```

First, use the `Array.prototype.findIndex()` method to see if any of the `arr` entries has the same exact `Id` as the `obj`. The advantage of using this method is that it stops looking once a match is found.

```
const index = arr.findIndex(entry => entry.Id === obj.Id);
```

If there is a match, `index` would store the position of the match, which can be used to add a key of `person` to the object @ that location and set it to true.

```
if(index !== -1) {
  arr[index].person = true;
}

console.log(arr);
```